# Camera does not start in my app when using vidyo

Tags: android, vidyo

I am trying to implement vidyo.io in my android app. Everything looks good but I am unable to figure out why camera/video does not start in my app.

So, after giving CAMERA,INTERNET permissions in android.manifest file,

I have my video.java file where I am trying to use vidyo.

This is where my video should get started:

```
 public void Start(View v) {

    Connector vc  = new Connector(videoFrame, Connector.ConnectorViewStyle.VIDYO_CONNECTORVIEWSTYLE_Default,
            5, "warning info","", 0);
    vc.showViewAt(videoFrame, 0, 0, videoFrame.getWidth(), videoFrame.getHeight());
   }
```

upon clicking start button, a preview framework opens but video does not start.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out that camera permissions need to be explicitly given in the app as--

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},1);
```